# Setting javafx Property via reflection

Tags: java, data-binding, javafx-8, javabeans

Trying to set a value to observable Property via reflection (ORM case).

```
public class TestVAO
{
        private Property<Long> id = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
}
```

This code is not working. What is the correct way?

```
    if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(Property.class))
    {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(obj, value);
    }
```

Comment: What does “not working” mean?  If there is an exception, edit your code and include its full stack trace.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This did the trick. Is that correct way of doing this?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
final Property<Object> property  = (Property<Object>)field.get(obj);
property.setValue(value);
```